# Definition of short exact sequence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the definition of a short exact sequence we have, if we let $f_1: G_1 \rightarrow G_2, f_2: G_2 \rightarrow G_3$
$1 \rightarrow G_1 \rightarrow G_2 \rightarrow G_3 \rightarrow 1$
$ ker f_1 =\{ 1\}, im f_1= ker f_2 \cong G_1, im f_2 \cong G_2/G_1$. what am not getting from this definition is, how is $G_1\leq G_2$ ? It appears to be something trivial but I cannot find the reason why it holds

Comment: This is an identification. Identifying $G_1$ with the image of $f_1$. Whenever there is an injection $G_1 \longrightarrow G_2$, you can identify $G_1$ with it's image in $G_2$, and *by abuse of notation* consider $G_1$ as a subgroup of $G_2$.

Comment: Haha...I get it now its the abuse of notation. So precisely we need to write $G_2\ker f_2$?

Comment: I didn't understand. $G_1$ is not isomorphic to $G_2/\ker f_2$.

Comment: What I meant is that $G_3$ is isomorphic to $G_2/ker f_2$ but we make an abuse of notation by writing $G_2/G_1$ due to the existing isomorphism between $ker f_2$ and $G_1$

Comment: Yes...!!! That's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, $G_1\not\le G_2$ and $f_1$ need not be the inclusion homomoephism. For example,
$$1\to \Bbb Z\stackrel{\cdot(- 2)}\longrightarrow \Bbb Z\longrightarrow\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to 1 $$
is a s.e.s. where the $G_1$ happens to be a subgroup, but we do not consider the inclusion map, and in
$$1\to \Bbb Z\stackrel{\cdot 6}\longrightarrow 3\Bbb Z\longrightarrow\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to 1 $$
the subgroup property fails completely.

However, it is *often* the case that we either have $G_1$ as a subgroup of $G_2$, or that we *consider* $G_1$ as a subgroup of $G_2$ by the very monomorphism $f_1$ (using the fact that automatically $G_1\cong f_1(G_1)$).

Comment: Really nice...!!! I'm gonna use it (with an acknowledgement, of course). :)